# Output post count from Specific Custom Post Types in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

OK, So I have this.

```
<?php 
    $count_posts = wp_count_posts('attractions'); 
    echo $count_posts->publish; 
?>
```

I currently have the amount of attraction posts echoing out onto the page, however when I try to add another it break. How do I add say attractions and Restaurants together for example?

If I do

```
$count_posts = wp_count_posts('attractions', 'festivals'); 
echo $count_posts->publish;
```

it wont add the two together, so my question is how do I write it so it adds them together?

Comment: If I do it in a theme template, it works. Where exactly are you applying it? And what is the full code that's not working? Please, [add more details](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/14085985/edit) to the Question itself.

Comment: If I do <?php $count_posts = wp_count_posts('attractions', 'festivals'); echo $count_posts->publish; ?> it wont add the two together so my question was how do I write it so it adds them together? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your question is basic PHP.

```
$attractions_count = wp_count_posts('attractions');
$restaurants_count = wp_count_posts('restaurants');
$festivals_count   = wp_count_posts('festivals');
$total = $attractions_count->publish + $restaurants_count->publish + $festivals_count->publish;
echo $total;
```

Always check the [PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/langref.php).

Lots of [good tutorials](http://wp.tutsplus.com/tag/php/).

[WordPress Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/), essential.

Search this site before asking, probably you'll find many of your doubts already answered, PHP, Html, CSS and jQuery.

[WordPress StackExchange](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/) is also full of good material.

Comment: Hi Mate, I did check this however there wasnt anything specific to what I needed.what is it page_count? I dont want to count pages I just want to count posts. How would I count for post types attractions, restaurants and festivals for example?

Comment: @GlenWheeler, you are really missing the forest... Updated the answer with an example of your custom post types. Do a [PHP crash course](http://devzone.zend.com/6/php-101-php-for-the-absolute-beginner/), now! ;)